# Google People API - query parameter 'deleteContacts' not working

Tags: python, google-api-client, google-people-api

There is documented optional query parameter 'deleteContacts' here:
https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/contactGroups/delete

It is not working. I have group with two contacts on my test account. I deleted this group with parameter 'deleteContacts' set to true. Group got deleted but contacts remained. I tried official python api client and API explorer found on the documentation page and the results are the same.

Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like there's a bug with deleting contacts, an internal bug has been filed.

Comment: Thank you! Internal bug === I can not see progress?

Comment: Yeah you won't be able to see the progress, unfortunately we don't have an external bug tracker for Google People API.

Answer (score 0):

The fix should be live now. Please try again.